# Save Opened Files Per Project

Tags: aptana

I've been using Aptana and it is a great tool for web development. I don't know if I can resort myself going back to Notepad++

Anyway, I have multiple project on Aptana ... I think it is stored in a single workspace. But I switch over to other projects depending on my mood. In each project, I have multiple files opened and it kind of destroys momentum that I have to close the windows of my previous projects and open the files on the projects I want to work on.

My question: Is there a way to save the opened files per project. Like when i switch to Project A, all of the files I opened in project A will open. When I switch to project B, all of the files I opened in Project B is opened?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to play around with "workspaces", and although there isn't a very GUI oriented way of working with these collections yet, I came up with a workable solution!

Create a new folder in your home directory, and just call it "workspaces", then open up Aptana, and choose File -> Switch Workspace -> Other and then type in the path to the new "workspaces" folder, and then the name of the workspace.  I have one workspace called "generic" where I pretty much have every project loaded up.  Then I have a bunch of workspaces named after the project to which they are committed.  No more reluctance to switch tasks in Aptana!  No more opening up bits and pieces of projects in Notepad++ or Sublime!  Everything is good again!

Now all Aptana really needs to do is make a menu where you can click to select which workspace to use when aptana loads instead of having to remember your-exact_project-name and being able to refresh your memory by looking at all the workspaces you have.  Ideally they would impliment a kind of search/filter bar after you start typing your project name, and then a hoverup that say "hit enter to auto complete" since there's no standard practice as to whether tab or enter should be autocomplete, and sometimes making it enter can be anoying cause you just wanted to make a new project called 'ant' not load your engineering project named'antennas'.

Anyway, sorry for the formatting.  Hope this helps.